# JavaScript opening new window instead of tab when command run too early

Tags: javascript, jquery

I realize that you cannot control whether a browser opens a new *window* vs. a new *tab*, so this may have no solution.

The problem is basically that I run something like:

```
function runCommand() {
   //...
   window.open(url);
}
```

This runs from time to time if the user presses a special key or clicks.  That all works fine, and it will open a new window or tab based on the user's browser settings.  Great.

The problem is, I also have some code:

```
if (x.property) runCommand();
```

This will *always* open a the url in a new *window*, even though if you use `runCommand` at some other time on the same page, it will use a tab if that's the user's setting.

At first, I thought that it may have had to do with the page not being fully loaded, so I both tried wrapping it in `document.ready` and also using `setTimeout()` to some high number (like 5 seconds).  Even after doing that, `runCommand()` will *still* open a new window on the initial run even though it opens a new tab later on.  Has anyone experienced this behavior or know how to fix it?

**EDIT**: I created a fiddle that showcases the problem.  Please excuse the popup: http://jsfiddle.net/csPGU/

Comment: It is down to many things. What triggers the code? does the window.open have parameters to size a window, does the link clicked have a href and a target and so on. Show more code please. For some pointers see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086811/javascripts-window-open-function-inconsistent-does-not-open-pop-up-when-expect/10087463#10087463

Comment: @mplungjan I don't understand what you mean by "does the link clicked ..." -- it's not a link that gets clicked, `runCommand` is run in a variety of ways.  One of them can be clicking a div, and another can be a keydown on the entire document.  The window is opened via identical calls to `runCommand()` in both instances.

Comment: That fiddle will open a new tab in most browsers regardless of settings. If you add ,"_blank","width=500,height=500") you will likelier open in a new window if the browser allows it. ALso if the user clicks something, the window.open is allowed in more situations when popup blockers are active

Comment: I believe the behavior is that that window.open() will honor user's preferences if it was triggered from an event generated by user (mouse or keyboard). But it will open in new window (provided it wasn't blocked) if it was triggered by an automatic event such as setInterval() or setTimeout().

Comment: @mplungjan well I only tested this in two browsers and in both you are incorrect -- the fiddle opens in a new *window*

Comment: FF and IE open either a tab or a window exactly how they are told to do in the settings, with both methods.

Comment: @Teemu this is incorrect -- even the fiddle I pasted shows that it is incorrect.

Comment: I saw it on my own screen with my own eyes, when I opened your jsFiddle with IE9 and FF11.0. Then I closed the page, and switched settings, and then opening the fiddle again. Like I said, both browsers work as expected.

Comment: @Teemu don't know what to tell you.  This is simply not the case for me and some others.

Comment: Well, I opened the jsFiddle with both browsers at least 20 times, and got the same result each time. IE version I'm using is 9.0.8112.16421 64-bit Edition, but I couldn't find any accurate version number from FF 11.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it's something to do with the browser itself and the way that the browsers try to deal with windows that are opened programatically.

I assume that when you `runCommand` later on it's based on an event that has occurred (clicking on something for instance). Browsers generally allow new windows that are triggered by events, but block those that had no interaction (typically popups).

Comment: This appears to be correct -- when I update `openWindow` to run from `setTimeout`, it attempts to open in a new window even if the `setTimeout` was initiated by a click event.

Answer (score 1):

If `window.open` is executed from event handler, such as click, it will open in a new tab, otherwise it will open in a new window.

Comment: I doubt this. Could you please tell why then popup is still opened when I replace `openWindow()` with `$('a').click()`. http://jsfiddle.net/csPGU/1/

Comment: I should have clarified. Browser knows when click is triggered by user action - by actually clicking that link, as opposed to triggering click programmatically.

Comment: The same way browser decides whether to open popup or block it.